# Removing different string patterns from Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have the following column which consists of email subject headers:

```
Subject
EXT || Transport enquiry
EXT || RE: EXTERNAL: RE: 0001 || Copy of enquiry
EXT || FW: Model - Jan
SV: [EXTERNAL] Calculations
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
Subject
Transport enquiry
0001 || Copy of enquiry
Model - Jan
Calculations
```

and for this I am using the below code which only takes into account the first regular expression that I am passing and ignoring the rest

```
def clean_subject_prelim(text):
     text = re.sub(r'^EXT \|\| $' , '' , text)
     text = re.sub(r'EXT \|\| RE: EXTERNAL: RE:', '' , text)
     text = re.sub(r'EXT \|\| FW:', '' , text)
     text = re.sub(r'^SV: \[EXTERNAL]$' , '' , text)
     return text
df['subject_clean'] = df['Subject'].apply(lambda x: clean_subject_prelim(x))
```

Why this is not working, what am I missing here?

Comment: Try `df['subject_clean'] = df['Subject'].str.replace(r'(?m)^(?:EXT\s*\|\|\s*(?:RE:\s*EXTERNAL:\s*RE:|FW:)?|SV:\s*\[EXTERNAL])\s*', '', regex=True)`

Comment: Worked really well but can you explain how you came to this solution? I have some other patterns as well that I would like to replace with '' so how should I incorporate the same within the pattern that you have shown? For ex: how should I incorporate 
" [EXTERNAL] Fwd: " into this regex?

Comment: Add the `\[EXTERNAL]\s+Fwd:` alternative, see https://regex101.com/r/LcWZdr/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
pattern = r"""(?mx)  # MULTILINE mode on
^                   # start of string
(?:                 # non-capturing group start
   EXT\s*\|\|\s*(?:RE:\s*EXTERNAL:\s*RE:|FW:)? # EXT || or EXT || RE: EXTERNAL: RE: or EXT || FW:
 |                  # or
   SV:\s*\[EXTERNAL]# SV: [EXTERNAL]
)                   # non-capturing group end
\s*                 # zero or more whitespaces
"""
df['subject_clean'] = df['Subject'].str.replace(pattern', '', regex=True)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LcWZdr/1).

Since the `re.X` (`(?x)`) is used, you should escape literal spaces and `#` chars, or just use `\s*` or `\s+` to match zero/one or more whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `$` sign in the first expression and switch some of regex expressions from place. Like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def clean_subject_prelim(text):
     text = re.sub(r'EXT \|\| RE: EXTERNAL: RE:', '' , text)
     text = re.sub(r'EXT \|\| FW:', '' , text)
     text = re.sub(r'^EXT \|\|' , '' , text)
     text = re.sub(r'^SV: \[EXTERNAL]' , '' , text)
     return text

data = {"Subject": [
"EXT || Transport enquiry",
"EXT || RE: EXTERNAL: RE: 0001 || Copy of enquiry",
"EXT || FW: Model - Jan",
"SV: [EXTERNAL] Calculations"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['subject_clean'] = df['Subject'].apply(lambda x: clean_subject_prelim(x))
```